# Is this sentence grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, tenses

The following sentence is grammatically correct:

> He swung his legs, and sang a song.

But I'm unsure if this is correct:

> He swung his legs, singing a song.

It *sounds* correct to me, but I'm not sure about the present participle, unless what is meant is:

> He swung his legs, [and he was] singing a song.

Comment: Broadly, what is meant is indeed "He swung his legs, [and he was/while] singing a song" but where is your own research? How far did you get before what problem arose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ask whether the sentences are "grammatically correct" - which they are.
But, to me, they do not (necessarily) mean the same thing:

> He swung his legs, and [then] sang a song.

Although both parts of the sentence are in the simple past tense, it is not clear from your wording whether the two actions were sequential or simultaneous.

> He swung his legs, [while] singing a song.

Here, the first part of the sentence is in the simple past tense, but the second part is in a continuous tense and it is clear that the two actions were simultaneous.

So in summary:

- Yes, they are both "grammatically correct".
- But, the first sentence is ambiguous as to whether the two actions were sequential or simultaneous.
- In the second sentence, the two actions were clearly simultaneous.

Answer (score 1):

"He swung his legs, and sang a song."

Tense-wise, this is correct. But, it does't need a comma. Your "and" sufficiently links the two clauses.  If he was doing more than just swinging his legs you would insert a comma to list his actions.  Such as:

"He swung his legs, waving his arms and singing a song."

"He swung his legs, singing a song."

This sentence is correct.  Yes, your comma takes the place of your "and was".  There is no disagreement between your participles.

Comment: I suppose you were going for asonginance, but did you need to duplicate "a song"?

Comment: @HotLicks My bad.  Edited.